# How to use to_date and IFERROR in Google Sheets together?

Tags: date, google-sheets-formula

I have a date in format `Wed, 09 Dec 2020 10:57:15 GMT` and want turn it into `09/12/2020`.

If i do it with `=to_date(DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\b[0-9]{2}\s\D{3}\s[0-9]{4}\b")))` it works - the output is, like expected `09/12/2020`.

But if i add IFERROR, like `=iferror(to_date(DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\b[0-9]{2}\s\D{3}\s[0-9]{4}\b"))),"")` the date turns into value, like `44174`.

How can i achive the correct date displaying with `iferror`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "\b[0-9]{2}\s\D{3}\s[0-9]{4}\b")), 
 "dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive why it works, but the following - just built on what you'd done - worked for me:

```
=IFERROR(to_date(text(to_date(DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\b[0-9]{2}\s\D{3}\s[0-9]{4}\b"))),"mm/dd/yyyy")))
```

Answer (score -1):

BTW, i figured it out to get date displayed through changing of the order of `IFERROR` and `TO_DATE`.

The working formula is now `=to_date(iferror(DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\b[0-9]{2}\s\D{3}\s[0-9]{4}\b")),""))`.